docker-java-api start ubuntu container Exited（0）
I used docker-java API to create Ubuntu container and exited immediately. My code as following:
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("ubuntu:18.04").withCmd("/bin/bash")
                .withName("ubuntu19").exec();
        dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();

Can someone could give me help?
